# How to get the selected value from the list in C# WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, combobox

I need to display the value in combo box and also I need to save the selected value from the combo box. In order to display the value in combobox I have list. I can display the values in a combo box. How can I get the selected value from the combobox in order to save?

```
_TheList.Add("Accecpted");
_TheList.Add("Not Accecpted");

public List<string> _TheList = new List<string>();
    public List<string> TheList
{
    get
    {                
        return _TheList;
    }
    set
    {
        _TheList = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("TheList");
        
    }
}
public void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
{
    if (PropertyChanged != null)
    {
        PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}

public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
```

XAML:

```
        <DataTemplate>
            <ComboBox                                      
               ItemsSource="{Binding TheList}"
               SelectedIndex="0"        
               IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"
              />
        </DataTemplate>
```

Comment: SelectedItem="{Binding yourProperty, Mode=TwoWay}"

Comment: Thanks for your idea. But i need to selected value in c# in order to save the value. substanceData.Add(new XElement(_substanceProperties[14], sr.TheList)); In TheList i need the selected value.

Comment: There are two ways to do it:
- Bind the the SelectedIndex to a property with TwoWay or OneWayToSource mode, then subscribe for the change event of that property and write a logic which looks for the element in the list based on the selected index.
- Bind the SelectedItem to a property, as @Steve mentioned above, and subscribe for the change event of that property.

Comment: @PraveenGopal which is exactly what the code I posted does

Comment: @steve  SelectedItem="{Binding TheList,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" I did like this. I am getting object reference not set to an instance of an object error.

Comment: @PraveenGopal the selected item is **not** a list, it's a single item. Declare the property (like you declared the list) in your viewmodel and it will get filled up automatically.

Answer (score 1):

in your c# code, add the following property

```
string _selectedItem;
public string SelectedItem
{
    get
    {
        return _selectedItem;
    }
    set
    {
        _selectedItem = value;
        PropertyChanged("SelectedItem");
    }
}
```

in your xaml

```
<ComboBox                                      
    ItemsSource="{Binding TheList}"
    SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem, Mode=TwoWay}"
    SelectedIndex="0"        
    IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"
/>
```